# AndEngine Making Chase Camera Follow Player

Tags: android, java, camera, andengine

I am playing around with the AndEngine Race Game example.  I am trying to make the camera follow the car as the player moves around.  The Tile Map is larger than the player's screen but the camera does not follow the car when it moves.

Here's my code:

```
this.mScene = new Scene();
//this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));

/** Tiled Map Test **/
try {
    final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(this.getAssets(), this.mEngine.getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, 
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new ITMXTilePropertiesListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTMXTileWithPropertiesCreated(final TMXTiledMap pTMXTiledMap, final TMXLayer pTMXLayer, final TMXTile pTMXTile, 
                final TMXProperties<TMXTileProperty> pTMXTileProperties) {
            /* We are going to count the tiles that have the property "box=true" or "boxBool=true" set. */
            if(pTMXTileProperties.containsTMXProperty("box", "true")) {
                SpeedsterGameActivity.this.numBoxes++;
            }
        }
    });
    // Load the TMX file into an Object
    this.mTMXTiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("tmx/level3.tmx");
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText( SpeedsterGameActivity.this, "Box count in this TMXTiledMap: " + SpeedsterGameActivity.this.numBoxes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
} catch (final TMXLoadException e) {
    Debug.e(e);
}

// Get the first TMX Layer and add it to the scene
final TMXLayer tmxLayer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);
this.mScene.attachChild(tmxLayer);
        /* Make the camera not exceed the bounds of the TMXEntity. */
this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBounds(0, 0, tmxLayer.getHeight(), tmxLayer.getWidth());
this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBoundsEnabled(true);

/* Debugging stuff */
Debug.i( "Game Info", "Height & Width: " + tmxLayer.getHeight() + " x " + tmxLayer.getWidth() );

int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
GLES20.glGetIntegerv( GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
Debug.i("Game Info", "Max texture size = " + maxTextureSize[0]);
/**********/
        /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera. */        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mVehiclesTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mVehiclesTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
        /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */
final AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY, this.mVehiclesTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(player);
/********************/

this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 8, 1);
```